# Basic Question Linear Transformation and Matrix computations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose that $T:\Bbb R^2 \to\Bbb R^2$ is a linear transformation satisfying the following: $$T\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\-6\end{pmatrix},\quad T\begin{pmatrix}2\\5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\5\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> 1. find the standard matrix $A$ of $T$.
> 2. find the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$.
> 3. find an eigenvector for each eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$.

Can someone show me how to do this question? I'm studying for a test and this was a question off a past test. I would love to show my thoughts but I do not know how to format on this forum. I do not know what the standard matrix is.

I think I would have to do:

$$\begin{pmatrix}-2&2\\-6&-5\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&5\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The solution to your last equation, with a typo corrected, is
$$\begin{align}
A & = \begin{pmatrix}-2&2\\-6&5\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&5\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\\
& = \begin{pmatrix}-2&2\\-6&5\end{pmatrix} \frac1{1 \cdot 5 - 2 \cdot 3} \begin{pmatrix}5&-2\\-3&1\end{pmatrix}\\
& = \begin{pmatrix}16&-6\\45&-17\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$
where I used the [formula for the inverse of a two-by-two matrix](http://www.mathwords.com/i/inverse_of_a_matrix.htm). With larger matrices, you might want to solve using row reduction.

Next, you can calculate $A^{-1}$ using that same formula. I assume you know how to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors, so here are the answers so you can check your work: $A^{-1}$ has an eigenvalue $1$ with eigenvalue $[2, 5]^\text t$ and another eigenvalue $-\frac12$ with eigenvector $[1, 3]^\text t.$